# Django Rest Framework Assertion Error: Missing Meta.model attribute

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement Rest api using Django framework. But when I click on the url on the default index page it gives me an assertion error at/languages/ Class LanguageSerializer missing meta.model attribute

I made all the migrations after changes in models.py but it did nothing

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('languages', views.LanguageView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    paradigm = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Language

class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'paradigm')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Language
from .serializers import LanguageSerializer

class LanguageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer
```

I have no clue where am I going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify what model you want to serialize in the `Meta` class of your serializer, like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Language

class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Language  # specify the model
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'paradigm')
```

otherwise the serializer can not determine the fields of that model, and how it will serialize the data from these fields.